# Elliptic curve- Component of point

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

If $E/ \mathbb{Q}$ elliptic curve in the general Form of Weierstrass and $P=(x,y)$ a rational point of it, show that the first coordinate of the point $2P$ is

$$ x(2P)=\frac{x^4-b_4x^2-2b_6x-b_8}{4x^3+b_2x^2+2b_4x+b_6}$$
where
$$b_2=a_1^2+4a_2$$
$$b_4=a_1a_3+2a_4$$
$$b_6=a_3^2+4a_6$$
$$b_8=a_1^2a_6-a_1a_3a_4+4a_2a_6+a_2a_3^2-a_4^2$$

$$$$

I have done the following:

$y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6$,  then

$$\lambda=\frac{3x_1^2+2a_2x_1+a_4-a_1y_1}{2y_1+a_1x_1+a_3}, v=\frac{-x_1^3+a_4x_1+2a_6-a_3y_1}{2y_1+a_1x_1+a_3}$$ and then $$2P=(\lambda^2+a_1 \lambda-a_2-x_1-x_2, -(\lambda+a_1)x_3-v-a_3)$$ 
$P_1=P_2 \Rightarrow x_1=x_2=x, y_1=y_2=y$
$$\lambda^2+a_1 \lambda-a_2-x-x= \\ \left ( \frac{3x^2+2a_2x+a_4-a_1y}{2y+a_1x+a_3} \right )^2+a_1 \frac{3x^2+2a_2x+a_4-a_1y}{2y+a_1x+a_3}-a_2-2x \\ =\frac{(3x^2+2a_2x+a_4-a_1y)^2}{(2y+a_1x+a_3)^2} +a_1 \frac{(3x^2+2a_2x+a_4-a_1y)(2y+a_1x+a_3)}{(2y+a_1x+a_3)^2}-\frac{(a_2+2x)(2y+a_1x+a_3)^2}{(2y+a_1x+a_3)^2} \\ = \frac{12a_2x^3-6a_1x^2y+4a_2^2x^2+6a_4x^2-4a_1a_2xy+4a_2a_4x+a_1^2y^2-2a_1a_4y+a_4^2+9x^4}{(2y+a_1x+a_3)^2}+\frac{3a_1^2x^3+6a_1x^2y+2a_1^2a_2x^2+3a_1a_3x^2-a_1^3xy+4a_1a_2xy+2a_1a_2a_3x+a_1^2a_4x-2a_1^2y^2-a_1^2a_3y+2a_1a_4y+a_1a_2a_3}{(2y+a_1x+a_3)^2}-\frac{2a_1^2x^3+8a_1x^2y+a_1^2a_2x^2+4a_1a_3x^2+4a_1a_2xy+8a_3xy+2a_3^2x+2a_1a_2a_3x+4a_2y^2+4a_2a_3y+a_2a_3^2+8xy^2}{(2y+a_1x+a_3)^2}$$

Is it right so far? How can we continue in order to show the desired result?

**EDIT**:
[image]

**EDIT 2**

**How can we find the tangent of the curve at the point $P$ ?**
[image]

Comment: Do you know what $2P$ is, geometrically? With this and your [other question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/21044/show-that-3p-1-2p-26p-3-0), it seems you are trying to apply formulas without really knowing what you're doing.

Comment: This is not the place for a lecture, you should really read some background material from a textbook or something. I recommend [the book of Hoffstein, Pipher and Silverman](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/numbers/book/978-1-4939-1710-5) for an introduction to elliptic curves requiring not too much background.

Comment: @fkraiem I tried to use Wolfram but it failed... Which other program could I use?

Comment: [Sage](http://sagemath.org/), for example.

Comment: @fkraiem I registered... Is there a calculator?

Comment: I don't know how to use the web-based interfaces, I have it on my computer.

Comment: @fkraiem Could you maybe solve the system for me or is it too much work? :)

Comment: I'm not even sure what exactly you are trying to do, other than that it has something to do with adding unspecified points on unspecified elliptic curves. Maybe you should clarify that and ask a new question, we have been talking here for far too long.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19855/discussion-on-question-by-evinda-elliptic-curve-component-of-point).

Comment: Ok @DanielFischer :)

Comment: No problem, @evinda, it's just to remove some clutter from under the question after the fact. Having such clarifying comment threads is no problem while they are still used (I didn't notice that the last interactions here were so recent, I'd have waited longer if I had noticed).

Answer (score 3):

In the first line you already have given the general Weierstrass form for the affine curve.
The other one is just the associated projective curve, where you obtain the affine part by setting $z=1$. So the difference is only whether you want to consider the affine or projective Weierstrass form for your elliptic curve. Usually, the affine form is used, with the formula for $2P$, as you have written (with $P=(x_1,y_1)$ ?). Note that there are typos in your formula, e.g. $2_3y_1$, and what are $x_2,x_3$ ?

Comment: Dietrich I edited my post... Could you tell me if it is right so far?

Comment: Yes, we have $x_3=λ^2+λa_1−a_2−2x$, with $\lambda$ as above. Then you are done. There is no need to expand this further.

Comment: Dietrich The answer should be $$x(2P)=\frac{x^4-b_4x^2-2b_6x-b_8}{4x^3+b_2x^2+2b_4x+b_6}$$ where $b_2=a_1^2+4a_2, \\ b_4=a_1 a_3+2a_4, \\ b_6=a_3^2+4a_6, \\ b_8=a_1^2a_6-a_1a_3a_4+4a_2a_6+a
_2a_3^2-a_4^2$

Comment: In the formula that I found there is also the variable $y$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: You have not done something wrong. The results are equivalent, because $P=(x,y)$ satisfies the elliptic curve equation.

Comment: But how can I get $$x(2P)=\frac{x^4-b_4x^2-2b_6x-b_8}{4x^3+b_2x^2+2b_4x+b_6}$$  ? Do I have to solve for $y$ at the ellipitc curve equation and replace it at what I have found?

Comment: Dietrich  The equation of the tangent is $y=\lambda x+v$. To continue, should we find the point $PP$ which is the intersection poit of this line with the curve? If so, do we have to replace $y=\lambda x+v$ at the equation of the curve?